# Alfresco compatibility with Existing Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I have installed Enterprise Version of alfresco and trying to use it with existing Oracle DB schema. 
For that I have changed properties in `alfresco-global.properties` file from PostgreSQL to Oracle.

And I am getting authenticate error while login into alfresco admin.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#48ff4096' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
```

Comment: Could you please show us your alfresco-global.properties ? Or at least the interresting part of the configuration.

Comment: Your simplest option is probably just to phone up Alfresco Support - you're paying to Enterprise and they're there to help you with your setup!

Comment: Actually I have downloaded trial version of Enterprise Edition to check compatibility with our system.

Comment: ## database connection properties ##
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.username=test
db.password=admin
#db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
#db.username=alfresco
#db.password=admin
#To use encrypted properties for the database uncomment the following line
# the encrypted value is added into alfresco-encrypted.properties
#db.password=${db.password.enc}
#db.username=${db.username.enc}
db.name=test
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.28.12.14:1521:BVTUCPS
#db.name=alfresco
#db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
  Comment out prop for Postgres and add prop for Oracle